# How it is syntactically correct?PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

I have this code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php
                    <ul>
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        <li><?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );?></li>

                    endwhile;
                    </ul>

                    zdwpbs_paging_nav();

                else :

                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

                endif;
          ?>
```

I receive this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 34`

How is correct in terms sintatic? What should I do to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<ul>` <- Is not PHP code.

Comment: you're injecting pure HTML into PHP. *Think echo*

Comment: all html needs to be outside the <?php  ?>

Comment: Are you seroius? Use [php.net](http://php.net)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert html in `<?php` or if you want to do it you can use echo.

Example.`<?php echo '<ul>';?>`

Correct code:

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>


                    <ul>
                 <?php   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <li><?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );?></li>

<?php                    endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>

<?php                    zdwpbs_paging_nav();

                else :

                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

                endif;
          ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <ul>
               <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
            <li>
               <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );?>
            </li>
               <?php endwhile;?>
            </ul>
            <?php
                    zdwpbs_paging_nav();

                else :

                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

                endif;
             ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if (have_posts()): 
?>
<ul>
<?php 
        while (have_posts()): the_post(); 
?>
            <li><?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?></li>
<?php 
        endwhile; 
?>
</ul>
<?php 
        zdwpbs_paging_nav();
    else :
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

    endif;
?>
```